# Getting Better Output from JSDoc3

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm having some trouble getting started with JSDoc3.  Most importantly, the `@param`s don't show up!

Here's my test source:

```
/**
 * Testing JsDoc3.
 * Why isn't this working `better`?
 */
function foo(bar) {
    console.log(+bar);
}

/**
   A function with params.
   @param {string} baz
   @param {...number} bim
 */
function goo(baz/*, ...bim */) {

}

/**
 * Hello, is this thing on?
 * @namespace bop
 * @type {object}
 */
var bop = {

    sting: function(WHO) {
        console.log(WHO);
    },

    buzz: function(when, why) {

    }

};
```

And I'm running `./jsdoc -r -l test.js`. The problem is the output I get is pretty bland and lacks a lot of information:

---

[image: JSDoc3 output]

---

Why no parameter information?! I'm using the default template; is the default template really so bland as to not show the parameters? Or am I doing something wrong?

I tried looking for some templates for JSDoc3 and haven't really been able to find anything good. If you know of a good one that works and actually contains helpful information, please share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was some problems when documenting global objects in previous versions of JSDoc3 in the latest version everything is working well.

If you try again with the latest version you will get parameters for your goo global function.

But if you want to get a better description you should follow the rule

@param {type} param_name Parameter Description
@param tag, type, param name, parameter description

The foo global function will not give you any information because the @param tag is missing.
Here's my output for your code

[image: global functions]

[image: namespace object]

I added some tags to your original code:

/**
     * Testing JsDoc3.
     * Why isn't this working `better`?
     * @method
     * @param {Object} bar Som bar value
     */
    function foo(bar) {
        console.log(+bar);
    }

```
/**
   A function with params.
   @param {string} baz
   @param {...number} bim
   @returns {boolean} return false because we're testing
 */
function goo(baz/*, ...bim */) {
    return false;
}

/**
 * Hello, is this thing on?
 * @namespace bop
 * @type {object}
 */
var bop = {

    /**
    * Hello, is this thing on?
    *
    * @method
    * @param {object} WHO Some Param
    * @memberof bop
    */
    sting: function(WHO) {
        console.log(WHO);
    },

    /**
    * I'm public
    *
    * @method
    * @param {object} when Some Param when
    * @param {object} why Some Param why
    * @memberof bop
    */
    buzz: function(when, why) {
        _buzz(when, why);
    },

    /**
    * I'm inner (private)
    *
    * @inner
    * @method
    * @param {object} when Some Param when
    * @param {object} why Some Param why
    * @memberof bop
    */
    _buzz: function(when, why) {
        console.log(when);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it depends on the jsdoc3 template you are using. I generated an output using several templates so we can compare which is the most suitable according to one's needs: https://cancerberosgx.github.io/jsdoc-templates-demo/demo/ I will put more with time but I think this is really helpful to make a decision. Also its documented how each of them is generated. Hope it helps!